# How to get some of the UserModel fields into another Serializer

Tags: django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I have a model name Comment as follows.

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    message = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    sender = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='usercomment')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.sender.name
```

For this model, I have a serializer

```
class CommentSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    id = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True)
    time = serializers.DateTimeField(read_only=True)
    message = serializers.CharField(read_only=True)
    
    sender = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(read_only=True, many=False)
    name = serializers.StringRelatedField(
        source='sender', read_only=True, many=False)
```

I want to obtain avatar field from use model so I'm going with a new sterilizer to nest into comments

```
class SenderInformation(serializers.Serializer):
    avatar = serializers.ImageField(read_only=True)
```

And the main objective is to bring an avatar field linked to the sender, as I'm already getting the user id in send field and name as well but any other way to get a user avatar instead of nesting the few fields from the used model. ?
How can I achieve this?

Comment: Because you need a ModelForm where heredate from Comment, and you can add there a field call avatar. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/forms/modelforms/ and add you ImageField in the model.

Comment: I'm not using Django forms at all, So why do I have to use that specifically?

Comment: I'm just making get Requests not the post

Comment: Because in a Form is defined the ImageField and we wan't deserialize a image.

Comment: What will be refactored code? can u post the solution? using this available code.

Answer (score 0):

Try `StringRelatedField`. You are already using it to get the name of the sender, which is being extracted from the user model. So to get an avatar, you can do this:

```
avatar = serializers.StringRelatedField(source='sender.avatar', read_only=True, many=False)
```

So the full `CommentSerializer` will look like this.

```
class CommentSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    id = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True)
    time = serializers.DateTimeField(read_only=True)
    message = serializers.CharField(read_only=True)
    sender = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(read_only=True, many=False)
    avatar = serializers.StringRelatedField(
        source='sender.avatar', read_only=True, many=False)
    name = serializers.StringRelatedField(
        source='sender', read_only=True, many=False)
```

You can learn by reading the [docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#stringrelatedfield) as well.

But there's is one issue with that, it will return the path as a string. So You should use simple ImageField for this purpose.

```
avatar = serializers.ImageField(source='sender.avatar', read_only=True )
```

That should work Perfect.

Comment: thanks, that's working as I wanted.

Answer (score -2):

Add a ImageField in your model:

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    message = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True),
    avatar = models.ImageField(),
    sender = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='usercomment')
    def __str__(self):
        return self.sender.name
```

In your forms.py

```
from django import forms

class CommentForm(forms.Form):

    message = forms.CharField(max_length=1000)
    time = forms.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True),
    avatar = forms.ImageField()
```

You call it in your view as:

```
f = CommentForm(request.GET)
```

Comment: I'm not making any Post requests.

Comment: I asked questions to the serialzer avatar field of the user model into the comments serializer.